# Why can't import os; precede this in python3 terminal in a single line?

Tags: python-3.x

I know I used to do it but now I can't remember so I try `import os; for f in os.listdir('dirname'): os.rename(f, f.replace('somestring', ''))` and get syntax error.

It seems I can type `import os; print("ok")` ok but if I try `import os; for f in os.listdir('.'): print(f)` it's invalid syntax, and if I leave out the `import os;` I get an ellipsis with or without a closing `;`

Comment: What does the SyntaxError say?

Comment: And what do you mean that `import os` gives you an ellipsis? That should not be possible. Do you run any other code before you start the Python process? How is the Python process started?

Comment: I type python3 to get into the shell. `import os` doesn't give the ellipsis, the next line does, then if I hit enter it executes, i.e., with or without the closing `;`

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`